# PHP7 Undefined class constant triggering php7:notice

Tags: php

I have been renaming some constants in our code and when releasing to production I get regulary in the apache log the following message :

```
[Sun Feb 16 19:56:29.437393 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 15948] [client 10.0.1.10:24984] Undefined class constant 'SUBMIT_STA_', referer: https://xxxx.yyyy.com/runtest/QuestionDisplayer
```

Nothing after, nothing before. There are many things I don't understand :

- How can an undefined class constant trigger a notice rather than a fatal error ?
- Why don't I get any more information about where in the code the error appears (like script and line number) as for other errors?
  Obviously, when I look into my code I don't find any instance of SUBMIT_STA_, I find some SUBMIT_STA_XX or SUBMIT_STA_YY but no SUBMIT_STA with nothing after.

Comment: Note that since 7.2 use of non-existent constant triggers warning, it triggers notice prior to that version though. https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.undefined-constants

Comment: Thanks, I am using 7.3.13 but the warning would look like :"Use of undefined constant Z - assumed 'Z'', then the line of the error and the call stack would be displayed

Answer (score 0):

If a constant doesn't exist, it will treat the constant name as a string,

Usually, what happens is that you write a string and forget the quotes, so for PHP that is a constant, not a string, but since there is no constant with that name, it converts it to a string and caries on the execution of the code.

so you want to look through your code and find the string `SUBMIT_STA_` where it is missing the quotes (or the `$` sign if it is supposed to be a variable)

Comment: I am afraid that's not it. What you describe would trigger a message like  Warning: Use of undefined constant Z - assumed 'Z' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) and there would be the full call stack, the line number where  it has been triggered etc... It 's not the case here.

Comment: @thesailorbreton Did you get that error in your development environment or in the same production environment? There may be some reduced logging in production when configured as such

Comment: I had the same error in the log in Dev and I have understood why. This happens when the error is in a try / catch (Throwable $e)  handler. No error is triggered on the screen and only a notice is displayed in the log.

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry I solved it. I finally found where I was using this unexisting constant. The reason for which it triggers this unusual message is because it was inside a try / catch(Throwable $e) handler, in such case no error is displayed on screen and Apache logs a [php7:notice] message. I have been able to reproduce this behavior.